# Spinner behavior for editext

Tags: android, spinner

I am developing sample shopping cart application in that i need to display 
predefined locations only. I found this behavior in some android applications.
Can you please help how to achieve this.

I need this behavior for edittext.

when the activity starts i need to display default city from the predefind cities like this.

[image: spinner behavior for edittext]

.

after clicking on edittext field i need to display predefind cities list as drop down, in that user has to select one from the drop down list. And user should not enter any thing in the edit text. I Used autocompleteTextView but i am not satisfied with that.

Could some help me on this?

Thanks
Naresh.

Comment: use AutoComplitTextView in this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spinner` and set it's background like `EditText`.

Use [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) for background resource generator. It will generate the same background resource as you describe in question.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but it looking very hard.

Comment: @Naresh Which part of my suggestion looks hard for you?

Comment: No No, If i use Android Holo Colors Generators the view looking hard.

Comment: @Naresh  you don't need to modify your existing style xml. Just copy the background resource and use as background of spinner.